# json_encode array shows 'size=0'

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to call some products from my db by category, everything is working but when I use the var_dump it tells me that the array is empty. I think showing my code would explain it all.

this is my function that calls the item by category ("productos.php")

```
public function getItemsByCategory($category){
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE categoria = :cat');
    $query->execute(['cat' => $category]);
    $items = [];

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $item = [
                'id'        => $row['id'],
                'nombre'    => $row['nombre'],
                'precio'    => $row['precio'],
                'categoria' => $row['categoria'],
                'imagen'    => $row['imagen']
                ];
        array_push($items, $item);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

and this is the code that show me the status and if correct the items

```
<?php

include_once('productos.php');

if(isset($_GET['categoria'])){
    $categoria = $_GET['categoria'];

    if($categoria == ''){
        echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 400, 'response' => 'No existe esa categoria.']); 
    }else{
        $productos = new Productos();
        $items = $productos->getItemsByCategory($categoria);

        echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 200, 'items' => $items]);
    }

}else{
    echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 400, 'response' => 'No hay accion.']); }

?>
```

and this is my var_dump

```
> array (size=2)
  'statuscode' => int 200
  'items' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: try `[':cat' => $category]`

Comment: Are you doing a var_dump() directly after $items = $productos->getItemsByCategory($categoria); ?

Answer (score 0):

Try  `$query->execute([':cat' => $category]);`  (add : before cat)

You are not getting any records from the database because your are not properly setting the category in your prepared statement.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php for examples

Comment: I added he " : " before cat but it didn't work, I'm looking forward to the link you send me and trying to figure out whats wrong with my statement. Thank you!